# Use Caps lock key to click without 3rd-party software

Tags: macos, keyboard, caps-lock

Clicking became very difficult on my early 2009, 17" MacBook Pro with Mavericks (10.9.1).
I thought about using the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to send a mouse click.

I saw [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/using-caps-lock-key-instead-of-right-click-contextual-menu) with an answer involving a third-party tool, but I wish to find a more low-level solution.

Comment: It would probably help to include which version of OSX you are using.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your problem is the battery which can swell and push up under the trackpad

Comment: What about a mouse?

Comment: or maybe enable tap-to-click so you don't have to physically press on the keyboard (I'm assuming it is broken in some way..?)

Comment: @Rob : a mouse is not a solution for a laptop (for instance in a plane) :-) but thanks for the idea.

Comment: @markhunte : indeed, it is perhaps the cause. but the battery is still functional so I will wait until it fails to change it. I hope it does not break more things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to do it without third party software, but it is possible with [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) and [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en).

First use PCKeyboardHack to change caps lock to F19. Then save this file as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>f19toclick</name>
    <identifier>f19toclick</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, PointingButton::LEFT</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.

Comment: ok, found your solution documented in https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en#faq - it is excatly what I needed. I used ``brew cask install pckeyboardhack`` and ``brew cask install keyremap4macbook`` to install using homebrew casks. Works like a charm, thanks!